# whitelist for allowed user queries in postgres

Tags: postgresql, security

Looking for a way to limited a user to a specific set of queries (i.e. a whitelist).

I currently need this as an extra security measure for a client app.

Is there a way to enable a table of "user allowed queries"? Anything that doesn't meet the regex pattern in that table (or however it works) receives a FATAL error.

**UPDATE for clarity:**

The client app only has 50 or so queries that ever execute, over and over again. So the list of expected queries is known. The only thing that changes between them is some values for `id` attribute in the `WHERE` clause.

For instance, I count these two `select` statements as 1 of the "50" (i.e. it's the same query, just the `x` value is different):

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM table_a
WHERE x = 1;
```

The next query may be:

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM table_a
WHERE x = 2;
```

What I'd ideally like to enforce is that **all queries** against the database should include a particular condition in the WHERE clause, `i.e. organisation_id = x` where the value of `x` would change depending on the user running the query.. but `organisation_id` exists in every table, and every query should contain this clause.

Comment: What kind of queries? Do you know how to use views? You can limit actions on views.

Comment: I've just updated the question to provide clarity around that.

Comment: I would simply create a set of views for the allowed queries and only grant that user select privileges on those views

Comment: Did you check row level security? It depends on the user

Answer (score 2):

> Looking for a way to limited a user to a specific set of queries (i.e. a whitelist).

Wrap all of your queries in a plpgsql function that takes a SQL command and executes dynamic SQL.

```
SELECT * FROM mystupidwrapper('SELECT * FROM foo');
```

It will have to return a specific type, `SETOF jsonb` sounds great. You can write `mystupidwrapper` in perl, or plv8 and it'll even be trusted. If you want to write it in plperl, you can even use [`SQL::Statement::Structure`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/SQL-Statement/lib/SQL/Statement/Structure.pod) to do basic SQL Statement processing. That said, SQL is a query language it provides READ permissions on both table and columns but the goal is still a declarative language that provides the ability to query abstractly.

Perhaps you want something more like `pg-promise` which natively supports a [QueryFile](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/QueryFile.html)